# Why Won't Calendar Generate any RSS?

Tags: 2010, calendar, rss

Salvete!  I have a calendar with one overlay.  When I go to view the RSS feed, it is blank - that is, there are no entries at all.

Now, for the calendar, RSS is enabled.
For the site, RSS is enabled.
I can view the RSS feeds of other lists on the same site - no problem.
The RSS is generated, but no entries are in it.

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't the RSS for a calendar produce entries?  Is there any way to get a clue as to what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if all your settings are correct, then you should know that Calendars don't generate any RSS unless you view it in Internet Explorer.  If you view it in Firefox, it will generate the feed, but without any entries.

View the RSS feed in Internet Explorer (or Firefox with IEtab).